# Div Click on Image / Slide to new div possible with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for some way to click on an image or link on a Div and it will slide to another div without changing to height...so something like the below

```
<div id="div1">
<img src="image.jpg" onclick="slide_to_other_div" />
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none">
<p>Another Div Here</p>
</div>
```

But I don't want an accordion effect... I want to slide to Div2 without affecting the height?

Explained further ...

Suppose you have a table>

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="div1"><a href="#div2">Slide to Div2 Direction --> </a></td>
  <td> id="div2" style="display:none">This is Div 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So, Div1 scrolls sideways to Div2 when I click on the link to Div2

Comment: Please make your question more specific. What do you mean by "without affecting the height"? The height of what? The `div`s? I see `div2` is hidden; should `div1` be hidden after the image has moved? What should happen to the `div`s visually?

Comment: Not really. I was going to suggest something like [slifty's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8744864/990877), but your question is still too vague. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not *entirely* sure I know what you want to have happen, but here are a series of steps which might accomplish your goal?

1. Calculate the current image height and explicitly set it so that it won't change.
2. Calculate the current absolute image position
3. Calculate the absolute div2 position
4. Detatch the image from div1, set it's style to be position absolute with the absolute position calculated earlier, and attach it to body
5. Animate the top and left properties of the position so it "slides" to the new location
6. Detatch the image from body, remove absolute positioning values, attach it to div2, and show div2

Does that sound like what you are looking for?  Each of those steps can be accomplished via jquery.

---

**EDIT:** Now that I think I'm understanding you more, you are probably looking for a horizontal accordian.  You could code this from scratch, but I would suggest looking at existing solutions to guide you (or to simply use).  [Here](http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/) is an example of one.  Google "horizontal accordian" to find more if that doesn't suit your fancy.

Comment: Sorry I think talking about an image has put everyone off what I need. There's a link on Div 1 and Div 2 is a hidden div ... When I click the Div 1 link it does a "Horizontal" scroll to Div B. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh so you're looking for a horizontal accordian (i.e. something like this: http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/)?

Comment: Almost but not exactly. I need a simple what to have a link on Div 1 and link to Div 2 where Div 2 will replace 100% the Div 1 space.

Comment: Understood -- I think that can be accomplished with some tweaking of accordion code :)  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

additional HTML:

```
<a name="myAnchor"></a>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#div1 img').click(function(){
window.location = "/currentpath_or_link#myAnchor";
});
```

It wont give you a nice animation but it will get you to there.
If you want a nice animation you will need the function `scrollTo()`
but I never worked with that.